# When testing sending stdout to another C program as stdin I get different results on Windows and Mac

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to have the output of one program (printf statements) be the input of another program, and have that second program write those statements to a file.

Here is my "read" program which works as intended on Windows when I pipe one program into the other with the command "test | read"

```
freopen("stderr.log", "w", stderr);
timestamp();

while ((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF)
{
    if (putc(c, stderr) == EOF)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failure: output error");
    }

    if (c == '\n')
    {
        timestamp();
    }
}

fprintf(stderr, "<End of program output>\n");
fclose(stderr);
```

However, when I try the same tests on my Mac, I see that no file is made and the output doesn't seem to go anywhere. It only creates a file when I run the "read" program directly and manually type in the input to the program via the terminal.

Does anybody know why this is happening? Or know what I have to do to make this functional on Mac as well?

Comment: You probably made an invalid assumption about where the current working directory is on the Mac. What are you using to build and run the code ?

Comment: hm I'm using plain old terminal with gcc on Mac. I could try putting a more specific file path in the program when I get home later.

Comment: No - it should be OK if you're doing it from the command line - I thought you might be using Xcode or some other IDE.

Comment: Note: Insure `c` is an `int`.

Comment: Also check the return status from `freopen`.

Comment: Might this be an old Mac and one should `if (c == '\n' ||c == '\r')`?

Comment: c is indeed an int. I can check the return status thanks. It's not an old Mac

Comment: I don't know what you're running it in on Windows, but in all shells I know of on Mac `read` is a built in command. Use `./read` to run your program.

Comment: I was using Visual Studio command prompt on Windows -- but I think you may have just figured it out... I'll be home soon to test and will let you know.

Comment: It works! Thanks for the suggestion. Can't believe I was that foolish!